# Why mongoose return empty results when I specify the path?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I defined two schema in mongoose: `DocSchema` has `DocTypeSchema` reference.

```
const DocTypeSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true, index: true }
});

export const DocType = mongoose.model('Doc-Type', DocTypeSchema);


const DocSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String },
    type: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Doc-Type' },
    description: { type: String },
  }
);
```

When I try to get the docs with type by the name I **gets empty results.**

How can I solve this?

```
 docs.find({ 'type.name': 'VideoBook' }, { limit: 30 })
```

- I don't want to get the `type` object inside the docs array. just to gets the docs that match to the query.

Answer (score 0):

You need tu user [.aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

Specify the collection:

```
const DocTypeSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true, index: true }
},{ collection: 'docType' });
```

Simple example :

```
const docs = await Doc.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'docType',
            localField: 'type',
            foreignField: 'name',
            as: 'magic'
        }
    },
    {$unwind: '$magic'},
    {
        $match: {
            $and: {
                "magic.name": 'VideoBook'
            }
        }
    },
    { $limit : 30 }
])
```

Comment: Join to the question, can I do it using `find`? cause I use `express-restify-mongoose` which run my query using `find` function.

Comment: @ShlomiLevi how aggregate with express-restify-mongoose [git](https://github.com/florianholzapfel/express-restify-mongoose/issues/287#issuecomment-307648611)

Comment: As far as I know with find you can't